# One variable returning from PHP in AJAX request but another not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two similar variables that are returned by an AJAX request - `country` and `salt`. The former returns correctly, whereas the latter is empty.

However, I know that the variable is fine until the final `else` loop in the PHP script because the salt is correctly added to the hash in this line: `$hash = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);` to do the verification.

However, when I alert it in the Javascript, it returns `{}`.

JS:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/login.php",
    data: $('#login-form').serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
        if (data == 'Incorrect email or password')
        {
            $('#login-response').hide();
            $('#login-response').fadeIn();
            $('#login-response').html(data);
        }
        else
        {
            chrome.storage.local.set({'country': data.country});

            chrome.storage.local.get('country', function (result)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // returns as expected
            });

            chrome.storage.local.set({'salt': data.salt});

            chrome.storage.local.get('salt', function (result)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // returns simply {}
            });
        }
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['loginEmail'];
$password = $_POST['loginPassword'];

include('connect.php');
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$query = "SELECT password
        FROM sh_users
        WHERE username = '$username';";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo "Incorrect email or password";
}

else
{
    $query = "SELECT *
        FROM sh_users
        WHERE username = '$username';";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $salt = $userData['salt'];
    $country = $userData['country'];
    $gender = $userData['gender'];

    $hash = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);

    if ($hash != $userData['password'])
    {
        echo "Incorrect email or password";
    }
    else
    {
        $data['salt'] = $salt;
        $data['country'] = $country;
        echo json_encode($data, true);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If I were debugging this, I would use a web inspector and look at what was actually returned by the request.

Comment: Try `data=$.parseJSON(data);` in first line of your else block. Also try using `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: Also, rather than using `alert`, I would use `console.log` and/or set a breakpoint and then output the variable (or just look at local variables on the side).

Comment: Please don't use hash for hashing passwords. It's not secure. Use http://docs.php.net/password_hash with http://docs.php.net/password_verify. Or you can use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat if you're stuck on older php version